# Flutter Camera Package - How to Fix Stretched Camera Preview?

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-camera

[image: there is clear difference]

I integrated the Flutter camera package into my app, and while the functionality is working, the camera preview appears stretched. I want the camera preview to resemble the normal mobile camera view. Has anyone encountered this issue, and what steps can I take to ensure that the camera preview maintains a natural appearance without distortion?

i used diffrent ways like.

`return Scaffold(

```
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: viewModel.controller.value.aspectRatio/2,
          child: CameraPreview(viewModel.controller)),

    ],
  ),
);`
```

or something like this

`return Scaffold(

```
  body: Stack(
    children: [
     CameraPreview(viewModel.controller),

    ],
  ),
);`
```

I appreciate any guidance or code snippets to address this problem. Thank you!